# Will "char a[4096] = {0};" make elements of a be initialized as 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how does array[100] = {0} set the entire array to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017/how-does-array100-0-set-the-entire-array-to-0)
>   [how to initialize a char array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134458/how-to-initialize-a-char-array)

In c++, I want to initialize char array to 0s array.
Will `"char a[4096] = {0};"` do this?

Comment: Yes. This comment has more than 15 characters.

Comment: Just use memset(a, 0x00, 4096);

Comment: @AntonRoth The OP's solution is safer - there's no risk of missing some elements or writing past the end of the array.

Comment: BTW, `char a[4096] = {}` will also work.

Comment: @Anton if anything, use `std::fill`. There are way too many posts showing how many bugs PVS-Studio finds in open-source projects that involve `memset` and friends. `memset` gives you more than `std::fill`, namely, more potential for bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will... but keep in mind that a `char` being `0` is ASCII `NULL`... if you want it initialized to all `'0'` (character 0's) that won't work.

In this case:

```
memset(a, '0', 10);
```

Would be a better way to go... or

```
std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), '0');
```

Would be better yet.

Comment: `std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), '0');` would be even better. (notice how it *always* means "fill the whole array with zeros" and not "fill N elements of the array with zeros"; reminds me of Perl's "do what I mean" motto)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Good one, coming from a C background I'm not always aware of the nice standard methods like this. I've updated the answer to include your comment. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

(And this answer has at least 30 characters as well.)